# Numpy advanced indexing on a matrix given a condition

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

How do I select rows of a matrix with a specific condition using `np` indexing?

My matrix is

```
n = np.array([[1,2],[4,5], [1,22]])
```

and I would like to select the rows whose first element is greater than one. Something similar to:

```
n[lambda x: x[0] > 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
n[n[:,0] > 0, :]
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: `np.where` is optional, thanks @user2357112.

```
n[n[:, 0] > 1]
```

> Try
>
> ```
> n[np.where(n[:, 0] > 1)]
> ```
>
> where `np.where` returns an array of row indices that satisfy the
>   given condition.

Comment: Don't use `np.where`. Any indexing of the form `x[np.where(whatever)]` can be replaced with `x[whatever]`, and the code will be equivalent, more concise, and more efficient.

Comment: @user2357112 funny, I thought that returned an error. Thanks!